# Two assemblies depends on two different versions of the same other assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .net core 2.0 project where I'm facing some dependency resolving issues.

My project, lets call it WebApi, depends on package Foo on version 1.93. My WebApi also depends on package Bar on version 1.13. But Bar also depends on Foo, but on verson 1.91.
When WebApi calls Bar, I have an exception:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Foo, Version=1.91, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified..

How do I solve this kind of dependency binding problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd expect this to normally be resolved automatically via assembly binding redirects. Can you reproduce this in a simple console application that you can include in the question?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the `Specific Version` option? (Go into the project in solution explorer, expand references, right-click the dependency and select properties, then look for `Specific Version` and set it to false) Try this for both of them.

Comment: @JonSkeet Assembly binding redirects are, AFAIK, a .NET Framework concept, not a .NET Core one

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: They effectively still happen in .NET Core - they're just more automatic. You still have libraries depending on version X of another assembly, but end up receiving version Y. It's easier to just refer to that as "assembly binding redirects" than call it something else, IMO :)

Comment: @JonSkeet a thought it doesn't existed in .NetCore. Can you point me an article where I can read more about it? All I could find says it doesn't exists in .NetCore.

Comment: @AndreNascentes: I don't have a link for you, but I suspect those articles are more about it not being part of a config file that you have to maintain. But again, if you could provide a [mcve] that would really help us. (I'm sure it won't be too hard to find a library that depends on some old version of Json.NET or similar, which would make for an easy example.)